# QGIS GRASS Processing Not Working on MacOS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin, grass-7.2

Recently upgraded to QGIS3 (3.0.2) for MacOS (High Sierra) and encountered GRASS (7.2.2) issues. Tried [adding a custom variable](https://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180406_qgis_tools_processing_workaround) and now when running GRASS algorithms (e.g. r.reclass) I get the following error:

> WARNING: Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.
>
> Starting GRASS GIS...
>
> ERROR: Path '//' doesn't exist
>
> Default locale not found, using UTF-8
>
> Exiting...

The GRASS7 Path in Settings --> Options --> Processing seems to be correct. What am I missing?
[image: GRASS7 path]

Comment: Have you installed the [required frameworks](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/frameworks) for GRASS before installing QGIS 3.0? This might solve this issue. Also looking into https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250645 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198367 posts might help.

Comment: I first installed Python 3.6 and GDAL Complete 2.2 as instructed [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

Comment: [Installed in the order shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Mqx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing the new QGIS 3.4. I had the same issue, it has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently on windows. QGIS and QGIS with GRASS have separate launchers, and making sure I was launching "QGIS with GRASS" solved my issue.

[image: QGIS vs. QGIS with GRASS app launcher on Windows 10]