# Getting log error about default locale settings when using GRASS with QGIS?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-processing, qgis-3, python-3, qgis-grass-plugin

I downloaded python 3.6, installed it, dowloaded QGIS 3.0.2, installed GDAL, then QGIS, then opened QGIS and tried to use GRASS processing tools. Initially I got the following error:

```
env: python3: No such file or directory
env: python3: No such file or directory
Execution completed in 0.50 seconds
Results:
{'lake': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':/Users/yalngarpiril/Desktop/MAP/water/ocean/ocean.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}
```

I then followed the instructions to add a custom variable on kyngchaos.com. I quit and restarted QGIS and opened the same GRASS processing tool and got a different error:

```
WARNING: Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.
Starting GRASS GIS...
ERROR: Path '/<UNKNOWN>/<UNKNOWN>' doesn't exist
Default locale not found, using UTF-8
Exiting...
WARNING: Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.
Starting GRASS GIS...
ERROR: Path '/<UNKNOWN>/<UNKNOWN>' doesn't exist
Default locale not found, using UTF-8
Exiting...
Execution completed in 0.88 seconds
Results:
{'lake': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':/Users/yalngarpiril/Desktop/MAP/water/ocean/ocean.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}
```

I'm on a 2010 MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.13.4.

What causes my current error?

Comment: GRASS GIS 7.8.0 with Python 3 support as been released: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.8.0-News

Answer (score 2):

The second error can be for not installing the [required framework](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/frameworks) beforehand. Please see the answer in [QGIS GRASS Processing Not Working on MacOS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282997/qgis-grass-processing-not-working-on-macos/283001#283001) post which has two more references to consult.

Comment: I installed the framework, installed qgis 3.03, and tried using GRASS processing with and without kyngchaos's custom variable fix. The same to errors occurred.

Comment: @CallumCooper I am having the same issue. [Here](http://schernthanner.de/how-to-get-grass-gis-7-0-5-working-on-mac-os-sierra) is another guide I tried to follow, but it didn't work for me. Hopefully it will for you, though!